Need help in matching string using regex until the last occurrence of open-close parenthesis with optional value in open-close parenthesis
I have few below example strings with me on which using regex I have to get the portion of it until the last occurrence of open-close parenthesis with optional value in open-close parenthesis.
START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end ()END

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters () also lots of non-sense things () with boring end ()END

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end (III)END

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (1) also lots of non-sense things (2) with boring end (3)END

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (111) also lots of non-sense things (222) with boring end (333)END

And the result I am looking for:
START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end 

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters () also lots of non-sense things () with boring end 

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end 

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (1) also lots of non-sense things (2) with boring end 

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (111) also lots of non-sense things (222) with boring end 

First, I tried using the non-capture group concept like this, but I am getting only match until first match of open-close parenthesis. regex101
^(.*?)(?:\(.*\))END$

But I am getting only this much of output from all strings:
START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters 

Then I tried using negative lookahead along with non-capture group, regex101
^(.*?)(?:\(.*\))END$

But I am getting match including last occurrence of open-close parenthesis.
START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end ()

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters () also lots of non-sense things () with boring end ()

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end (III)

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (1) also lots of non-sense things (2) with boring end (3)

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (111) also lots of non-sense things (222) with boring end (333)

I am pretty sure that I am missing something small thing but I am not able to figure it out by myself.
I will glad if someone can point that out.

You could use a positive lookahead to do this:
^.*(?= \(.*\)END$)

This will capture anything followed by ([arbitrary characters])END
https://regex101.com/r/II2nu3/1
If END is something you added to explain your question in a better way and you just want everything before the last () pair, ^.*(?= \(.*\)$) will work

Thanks for solution. But one thing it is missing and that is to match a start and end of string with ^ and $ respectively. But when I add it in your regex then it is not working: https://regex101.com/r/rRuQfz/1. Am I missing something with positive lookahead?

Put the $ inside the positive lookahead: ^.*(?= \[.*\]END$)

As you are using .* in your initial pattern, you could also remove the part from the end of all the examples.
\s*\([^()]*\)END$

Or if you don't want to match any newlines:
[^\S\n]*\([^()\n]*\)END$

The pattern matches:

\s* Match optional leading whitespace characters
\([^()]*\) Match from (...) using a negated character class
END$ Match END at the end of the string

Regex demo 1 | regex demo 2
For example
import re

pattern = r"\s*\([^()]*\)END$"

s = ("START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end ()END\n\n"
            "START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters () also lots of non-sense things () with boring end ()END\n\n"
            "START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end (III)END\n\n"
            "START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (1) also lots of non-sense things (2) with boring end (3)END\n\n"
            "START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (111) also lots of non-sense things (222) with boring end (333)END")

print(re.sub(pattern, "", s, 0, re.M))

Output
START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters () also lots of non-sense things () with boring end

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (1) also lots of non-sense things (2) with boring end

START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (111) also lots of non-sense things (222) with boring end


The reason your regex doesn't work as expected is because your capture group has a lazy match (.*?) so it stops matching at the first ( it encounters. Instead, you should use a greedy match so that it continues matching until the last ( in the string:
^(.*)\(.*\)END$

Regex demo on regex101
Python usage:
import re

strs = [
  "START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end ()END\n",
  "START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters () also lots of non-sense things () with boring end ()END\n",
  "START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end (III)END\n",
  "START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (1) also lots of non-sense things (2) with boring end (3)END\n",
  "START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (111) also lots of non-sense things (222) with boring end (333)END\n"
]

pattern = re.compile(r'(.*)\(.*\)END$')

for s in strs:
    print(pattern.match(s).group(1))

Output:
START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end
START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters () also lots of non-sense things () with boring end
START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (I) also lots of non-sense things (II) with boring end
START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (1) also lots of non-sense things (2) with boring end
START OF THE SHOW with some gibberish characters (111) also lots of non-sense things (222) with boring end


You could use this one. It takes a look at any starting character, followed by a pair of parentheses with any char inside and after that looks if it is ened by END:
^(.*?)(?:\(.*?\))END$


I don't think this gives the expected result OP asked for?
